# finding the greatest common divisor of two polynomial, I'm stuck

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I'm trying to find the greates common divisor of two polynomials. The polynomials are:
\begin{align*}
p_1 &= x^3+3x+1\\
p_2 &= x^4+1
\end{align*} 
Matlab is telling me that the GCD is 1, and that's also what I was expected.

However when I try to do It by hand it dosn't equal to 1, so what am I doing wrong?(I'm using Long division and writing it as Euclidian algorithm).

\begin{align*} 
x^4+1 &= (x^3+3x+1) \cdot x -(3x^2-x+1)\\
x^3+3x+1 &=  (-3x^2-x+1) \cdot (\frac{-x}{3}+\frac{1}{9}) + (\frac{31x}{9}+\frac{8}{9})\\
-3x^2-x+1 &=  (\frac{31x}{9}+\frac{8}{9})\cdot (\frac{-27x}{31} - \frac{63}{961})+ \frac{1017}{961}\\
\frac{31x}{9}+\frac{8}{9}&=\frac{1017}{961}\cdot (\frac{29791x}{9153}+\frac{7688}{9153})+\frac{8}{9}\\
\frac{1017}{961} &= \frac{8}{9} \cdot \frac{9153}{7688} + 0 
\end{align*}

so the GCD should be $= \frac{8}{9}$??

Answer (score 2):

$8/9$ and $1$ are the "same thing" because there exists a unit in the ring $\mathbb R [x]$ that send one to the other (notice that $\frac{9}{8}$ is a unit).

You may be confused because the units in the ring of integers are only $1$ and $-1$.

The convention is to let $\gcd(P,Q)$ be monic when working with polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

By *greatest common divisor*, when talking about polynomials, this means, find the greatest $n$ for which $x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+...+a_1 x+a_0$ divides both of your polynomials. Then the greatest common divisor is $$x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+...+a_1 x+a_0$$
In your example, $n=0$, so the greatest common divisor is $1$.
 $\frac89$ is the same thing as it is just a scalar multiple of this, i.e. it is a polynomial of the same degree ($0$). We choose by convention that we want the coefficient of $x^n$ to be $1$, which is why MATLAB tells you it is $1$.

Comment: so $1$ because the degree is 0? or because $1x^0$?

Comment: @user32091 Yes since, $1=1\cdot x^0$ is a polynomial of degree $0$. You can say it in either way, since they are the same.

Comment: so it could be any number $n$ because $n \cdot x^0$ but we just by convention choose 1 ? Thanks ! @JohnDoe  One more question, i need to solve Bézout identity so $p_1U+ $p_2V = 1$ how to I do that ? Do i scale everything so 8/9 =1 or do I just use 8/9 insted of 1?

Comment: Yep it could be any $n$. Since the convention is to use $1$ (and it will likely make calculations much easier), I would still use $1$. I think Will Jagy's answer goes through this calculation.

Comment: John, I did the Extended Euclidean algorithm. I  like to write the "back-substitution" part as, instead, a simple continued fraction. Just as with ordinary integers, we get the 2 by 2 cross products coming out $\pm 1.$

Comment: I added an illustration (separate answer) of usage of the continued fraction. Here I just found $\gcd(355,113)$

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do for the Extended Euclidean Algorithm is not back substitution, which i can never remember, rather a (simple) continued fraction. There is not usually enough room with polynomials to write the continued fraction  part sideways, so I write that sequence  of fractions
vertically. The "extended" part then comes from the little 2 by 2 cross products always being $\pm 1.$ I cancel out some of the common factors, and in the end get 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 31 x^{2}  - 8 x  + 106 }{ 113 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 31 x^{3}  - 8 x^{2}  + 13 x  - 7 }{ 113 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$
which is a confirmation that the original polynomials are coprime.

```
PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?12 for how to get moral (and possibly technical) support.

    parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500509
    ? (x^4 + 1) * (31 * x^2 - 8 * x + 106) - (x^3 + 3 * x + 1) * (31 * x^3 - 8 * x^2 + 13 * x - 7) 
    %1 = 113
    ? hooray!
      ***   at top-level: hooray!
      ***                 ^-------
      ***   gtos expected an integer, got 'hooray'.
      ***   Break loop: type 'break' to go back to GP
    break> break
```

$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) } +  \left(   - 3 x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   - 3 x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 3 x  + 1 }{ 9 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 31 x  + 8 }{ 9 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   - 3 x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 31 x  + 8 }{ 9 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 837 x  - 63 }{ 961 }  \right) } +  \left( \frac{ 1017}{961 } \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{ 31 x  + 8 }{ 9 }  \right)  =  \left( \frac{ 1017}{961 } \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 29791 x  + 7688 }{ 9153 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 3 x  + 1 }{ 9 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 3 x^{2}  +  x  + 9 }{ 9 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 3 x  + 1 }{ 9 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 837 x  - 63 }{ 961 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 279 x^{3}  - 72 x^{2}  + 117 x  - 63 }{ 961 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 279 x^{2}  - 72 x  + 954 }{ 961 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 29791 x  + 7688 }{ 9153 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 961 x^{4}  + 961 }{ 1017 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 961 x^{3}  + 2883 x  + 961 }{ 1017 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 31 x^{2}  - 8 x  + 106 }{ 113 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 31 x^{3}  - 8 x^{2}  + 13 x  - 7 }{ 113 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$

Comment: Could you add a few sentences and words to this to add some structure? It is (probably - assuming calculations are correct) fine mathematically but I'm sure that would improve the answer considerable.

Answer (score 1):

This one is just an illustration of using simple continued fractions to solve $ax+by = 1.$ One convergent (good approximation) for $\pi$ is $\frac{355}{113}.$ Let us show the gcd is one and solve the Bezout thing

$$  \gcd( 355, 113 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 355 }{ 113 } = 3 +  \frac{ 16 }{ 113 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 113 }{ 16 } = 7 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 16 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 16 }{ 1 } = 16 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 7 & & 16 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 22 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 355 }{ 113 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  7  \\  
  \frac{ 22 }{ 7 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  16  \\  
  \frac{ 355 }{ 113 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  0  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 355 \cdot 7 - 113 \cdot 22 = -1 $$ 
Note how this is just a little 2 by 2 crossed product from the displayed convergents in the continued fraction.

===============================================================================

This time I made one with a little longer continued fraction.

$$  \gcd( 1393, 972 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 1393 }{ 972 } = 1 +  \frac{ 421 }{ 972 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 972 }{ 421 } = 2 +  \frac{ 130 }{ 421 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 421 }{ 130 } = 3 +  \frac{ 31 }{ 130 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 130 }{ 31 } = 4 +  \frac{ 6 }{ 31 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 31 }{ 6 } = 5 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 6 }{ 1 } = 6 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 & & 5 & & 6 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 10 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 43 }{ 30 }   & &   \frac{ 225 }{ 157 }   & &   \frac{ 1393 }{ 972 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 10 }{ 7 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 43 }{ 30 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 225 }{ 157 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 1393 }{ 972 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  0  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 1393 \cdot 157 - 972 \cdot 225 = 1 $$ 
Check how the cross products are all $\pm 1.$ For example $3 \cdot 7 - 2 \cdot 10 = 21 -20 = 1,$ then $10 \cdot 30 - 7 \cdot 43 = 300 - 301 = -1.$

Comment: I don’t understand all of it, How do u get The Numbers $\frac{0}{1}, \frac{1}{0},...,\frac{225}{157}. And how do u know how many digit they have?

Comment: @user32091 well, if you don't know continued fractions, this will not be attractive. Why don't you find $\gcd(1393, 972)$ and $1393x+972y = 1$ your way, see how the methods compare.